# How to create hyperlinks in VBA for mutiple cells?

Tags: vba, loops, hyperlink

I have to create hyperlinks for a list of variables to get easily to the datas in a database.  My database contains summary of many variables coming from different sources.  My problem is, I have to skip multiple rows fill with duplicates and blank cells.  The number of rows to skip depends for every variable.  I also want that my hyperlinks have the name of the variable from the database (example : Customer_Since).  Is there a way to create a loop to skip the good number of rows and create a hyperlink?  Example : if I click on the link named Customer_Since, it takes me to the row that contains the summary of the variable Customer_Since.  Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.  Check out [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Following the guidance there will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

To create a hyperlink you can use this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A10"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet2!B5", TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

where:

**Anchor** - cell, where there will be a hyperlink;

**SubAddress** - range to navigate to;

**TextToDisplay** - text in the link.

You can use another vba code with your rules to correctly insert Anchor`s range.
Or please provide more information and examples of the input and output data to get help.